# How to automatically update container image when new build released on Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a private repository. I want to update my container image in Kubernetes automatically when the image is updated in my private repository. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 14):

Kubernetes natively does not have the feature of automatically redeploying pods when there is a new image. Ideally what you want is a tool which enables GitOps style deployment wherein state change in git will be synced to the Kubernetes cluster. There is [Flux](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux) and [ArgoCD](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/architecture/) open source tools which supports GitOps.

Recently there is an [announcement](https://www.weave.works/blog/argo-flux-join-forces) to combine these two projects as ArgoFlux.

Comment: see also https://serverfault.com/questions/931808/kubernetes-detect-and-auto-update-deployment-on-image-update

Comment: Thanks for the info about the announcement. But I did they merged yet?

Answer (score 5):

You should assign some sort of unique identifier to each build.  This could be based off a source-control tag (if you explicitly tag releases), a commit ID, a build number, a time stamp, or something else; but the important detail is that each build creates a unique image with a unique name.

Once you do that, then your CI system needs to update the Deployment spec with a new `image:`.  If you're using a tool like Kustomize or Helm, there are standard patterns to provide this; if you are using `kubectl apply` directly, it will need to modify the deployment spec in some way before it applies it.

This combination of things means that the Deployment's embedded pod spec will have changed in some substantial way (its `image:` has changed), which will cause the Kubernetes deployment controller to automatically do a rolling update for you.  If this goes wrong, the ordinary Kubernetes rollback mechanisms will work fine (because the image with yesterday's tag is still in your repository).  You do not need to manually set `imagePullPolicy:` or manually cause the deployment to restart, changing the image tag in the deployment is enough to cause a normal rollout to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the various [image pull policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images).

`imagePullPolicy: always` might come closest to what you need. I don't know if there is a way in "vanilla" K8s to achieve an automatic image pull, but I know that RedHat's OpenShift (or OKD, the free version) works with [image streams](https://blog.openshift.com/image-streams-faq/), which do exactly what you ask for.

Comment: I will try to write a script for this.But i am not sure if is it proper solution

Answer (score 3):

The imagePullPolicy and the tag of the image affect when the kubelet attempts to pull the specified image.

`imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`: the image is pulled only if it is not already present locally.

**`imagePullPolicy: Always`: the image is pulled every time the pod is started.**

`imagePullPolicy` is omitted and either the image tag is :latest or it is omitted: Always is applied.

`imagePullPolicy` is omitted and the image tag is present but not :latest: IfNotPresent is applied.

`imagePullPolicy: Never`: the image is assumed to exist locally. No attempt is made to pull the image.

So to achieve this you have to ***set `imagePullPolicy: Always` and restart you pod*** and it should pull a fresh latest copy of image. I don't think there is any other way in K8s

[Container Images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images)

Comment: Thanks for answer.Yes we can do it by kubectl delete pod but i look for an full automated solution.Maybe i write a crontab script for achieve this.

Comment: It kills the entire containers this way.

Comment: Which is what I want. To automatically kill the container so that it restarts and pulls a newer image.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote a bash script to achieve this.My imagePullPolicy option is always and i am running this script with crontab.(You can check everytime with infinite loops).It is checking repository and if any change occured , it is deleting the pod (automatically because of imagePullPolicy set Always) and pulling updated image.

```
#!/bin/bash
registry="repository_name"
username="user_name"
password="password"

##BY this you can append all images from repository to the array
#images=($( echo $(curl -s https://"$username":"$password"@"$registry"/v2/_catalog | jq .repositories | jq .[])))
##Or you can set manuaaly your image array
images=( image_name_0 image_name_1 )
for i in "${images[@]}"
do
old_image=$(cat /imagerecords/"$i".txt)
new_image=$(echo $(curl -s https://"$username":"$password"@"$registry"/v2/"$i"/manifests/latest | jq ."fsLayers" | jq .[]))


if [ "$old_image" == "$new_image" ];then
echo "image: "$i" is already up-to-date"
else
echo "image: " $i" is updating"
kubectl delete pod pod_name
echo $new_image > /imagerecords/"$i".txt
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is provided by open-source project `argocd-image-updater`:

https://github.com/argoproj-labs/argocd-image-updater

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30429518)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).