# Automate docker pull commit and update kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have docker images hosted external at docker hub which get updates every week.

Currently i did

```
Docker pull
```

`Update some config files in the docker`

```
Docker commit

Docker push
```

Then manually change the image name at `kubernetes deployment yaml` file.

What is the best practise for me to automate this? Can this be initiated in kubernetes?

Comment: Search for "GitOps" on google -- there are several tools to automate this. There's nothing native in k8s that will do this for you out of the box.

Comment: @spinlok i have gitlab in placed, how do i make it automatically? by configuring the gitlab-ci.yml or something else? i only have access up to this layer, no access to the gitlab runner.

Comment: You'd need some tool that can update the `image:` tag in your Kubernetes Deployment manifest to point to the new unmodified upstream image.  Provide the config files using a Kubernetes ConfigMap.  You should almost never run `docker commit`; the workflow you have here ("update some config files") is prone to manual errors and isn't reproducible, but if your changes really do require a custom image, write a Dockerfile to add them in and set up a normal CI pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K8s doesn't support such a functionality (yet, at least!)

but you can use GitOps tools like Flux to automate this procedure,
also you could use scheduled jobs of k8s combined to bash or python scripts to automate the task.

you better check out this post too:
[Auto Update Container Image When New Build Released on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543373/auto-update-container-image-when-new-build-released-on-kubernetes)