# Auto update container image when new build is released into kubernetes with gitlab ci/cd and helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have a private repository. How can update my kubernetes automatically every time I deploy new build?

I found a similar post here: [Auto Update Container Image When New Build Released on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543373/auto-update-container-image-when-new-build-released-on-kubernetes)

But I already have the ImagePull set to always. And I’musing gitlab ci/cd and helm for the deployment.

Comment: Do you create a new unique imag tag for each build? and updating the Deployment manifest?

Comment: I still stand by my answer to the question you linked to.  Is this question any different from that one?

Comment: @DavidMaze in your comment, you mentioned ** If you're using a tool like Kustomize or Helm, there are standard patterns to provide this**.  Can you share anything related to helm please

Comment: And No. I’m not giving unique tag to each build! @Jonas

Comment: In Kubernetes you do kind of need to give a unique tag to each build.  Changing a Deployment's `image:` is the most straightforward way to trigger a redeployment.  If each build has a unique tag it's also very easy to roll back a bad build (mistakes do happen!) just by switching the `image:` back to yesterday's good version.